# Nested Dictionary Python:Update logic failing

Tags: python, dictionary

**My dictionary :**

```
d={'a':'a1,a2,a3,a4','b':'b1,b2,b3,b4',c:'c1,c2,c3,c4'}
```

and so on d,e,f,....

```
d2={'a1':'a11,a12,a13,a14,a15','a2':'a21,a22,a23,a24,a25'}
```

and so on for a3,a4,a5,b1,b2....

**Expected output**

```
dict1={'a':{'a1':'a11,a12,a13,a14,a15','a2':'a21,a22,a23,a24,a25'}}
```

and so on for rest

**My Output**

```
dict1={'a':{'a1':'a11,a12,a13,a14,a15'},'a2':'a21,a22,a23,a24,a25'}
```

and so on then again

```
 'b':{'b1':'b11,b12,b13,b14,b15'},'b2':'b21,b22,b23,b24,b25'}
```

**My Code:**

```
dict1={}
for i in d:
    q=d[i].split(",")
    for j in q:
        dict1[i] = {}
        if j in d2:
            dict1[i][j] = d2[j]
            dict1.update(dict1[i])
```

*Any help would be very useful*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try nested dictionary comprehension with list comprehension

```
d={'a':'a1,a2,a3,a4','b':'b1,b2,b3,b4','c':'c1,c2,c3,c4'}
d2={'a1':'a11,a12,a13,a14,a15','a2':'a21,a22,a23,a24,a25', 'b1':'b11,b12,b13,b14,b15','b2':'b21,b22,b23,b24,b25'}
dict1 = {k: {i: d2[i] for i in v.split(",") if i in d2} for k, v in d.items()})
print(dict1)
```

Output in this case

```
{'a': {'a1': 'a11,a12,a13,a14,a15', 'a2': 'a21,a22,a23,a24,a25'}, 'b': {'b1': 'b11,b12,b13,b14,b15', 'b2': 'b21,b22,b23,b24,b25'}, 'c': {}}
```

So if there will be values in d2 about the the c's they will be in the dict1 results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with:

```
dict1={}
for i in d:
    q=d[i].split(",")
    for j in q:
        if not dict1.get(i, None):
            dict1[i] = {}
        if j in d2:
            dict1[i][j] = d2[j]
```